# Reaction Force, Wall and Spheres

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

[image]

- Two identical spheres with weights of 10N.
- O and M is the center of the sphere.
- Ropes are identical and have same length
- Ropes are connected from point P.
  How much newton is the reaction force (T) of the vertical wall? (T=?N)

Note:
No friction
sin37=0.6
cos37=0.8
g=10

I found the answer 7.5 but it was false (true answer is 20)
I tried this steps:
[image]

Comment: You are failing to take into account the second sphere pressing the first one into the wall

Comment: How can I add this force to my calculations?

Comment: I would start by drawing the forces you are missing from the diagram, like the weight of sphere 2 against sphere 1.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Geometry]

Reaction Force, Wall and Spheres
\begin{align*}
&\textbf{Geometry}\\\\
  &L^2=h^2+R^2\,\quad\Rightarrow h=\sqrt{L^2-R^2}\\
  &\tan(\alpha)=\frac{h}{R}\\
  &\gamma=180-(90-\beta-\alpha)=90+\alpha+\beta\\\\
  &\textbf{Static}\\
  &\text{Ball 1}\\
  &\sum_y=-M\,g+F_R\,\sin(\gamma)=0&(1)\\
  &\sum_x=F_{r1}-F_R\,\cos(90-\gamma)=0&(2)\\\\
   &\text{Ball 2}\\
  &\sum_y=-M\,g-F_R\,\sin(\gamma)+F_{r2}\sin(\beta-90)=0&(3)\\
  &\sum_x=T_1+F_R\,\cos(\gamma)-F_{r2}\cos(\beta-90)=0&(4)\\\\
  &\text{Four equations for the unknowns  $F_R\,,F_{r1}\,,F_{r2}\,,T_1$}\\
  &\text{$F_{r1}$ Rope Force Ball 1}\\
  &\text{$F_{r2}$ Rope Force Ball 2}\\
  &\text{$F_{R}$ Constraint Force between Ball 1 and 2}\\\\
  & \boxed{T_1=M g \left[\tan(\alpha+\beta)-2\tan(\beta)\right]}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The reaction force seem to rope+rope+T. It's 20 newton without calculation, since wall support 2 spheres.